# How to categorize a value in excel?

Tags: excel, categories

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LitbK.jpg)

Hi guys, can help me here? from the picture, the objective is to categorize ID to A-E based on its number. Eg. 1 is A, 17 is D.

Is there any way to do this not using macro? Thanks!

Comment: INDEX/MATCH will do it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying, but i still having difficulties to use index/match, can give more example?

Comment: post the formula you have tried.

Comment: I couldn't see how to do it with index/match either - I can see how you can do it in the particular case where the columns just contain numbers 1-25, but not if they are a list of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do (the result should be the column name of the column in which each ID is found) and assuming that an ID cannot be present more than one time in the A:E columns, here is a working formula:

[image]